# Displaying Information From a Specific Field in the DB in an :collection with Simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the database the clients table has the name, phone and other data. But, if I create an association with Simple_form it displays the name in the options, is there a way that instead of displaying the name in the options of the form, to display the phone?

Here is the code I am currently using that displays the name.

```
<%= f.association :client, :required => false, :prompt => "Eliga Cliente", 
  :label => "Clients", :collection => Client.where(:status => true).order("id ASC") %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass label_method parameter and set it to the appropriate attribute.

```
<%= f.association :client, :required => false, :prompt => "Eliga Cliente", 
:label => "Clients", :collection => Client.where(:status => true).order("id ASC"),
:label_method => :phone %>
```